# Find volume of lower half circle $(x+1)^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$ revolving about $x$- axis

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

a) using the washer method
b) using cylindrical shells

*note: no need to evaluate the definite integrals. just a set-up

here are my answers:
a) $\pi \int_{-2}^{0}(1 - (\sqrt{1+(x+1)^2}+ 1)^2) dx$

b) $2 \pi \int_{0}^{1}(2y\sqrt{(1-(y-1)^2} - 1)dy$

i compared these using WolframAlpha but the results are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

a) the washer integral should be set up as

$$\pi \int_{-2}^{0}\left[1 - \left(1-\sqrt{1-(x+1)^2}\right)^2\right] dx$$

b) The cylinder integral should be set up as

$$2\pi \int_0^1 2y\sqrt{1-(y-1)^2}  dy$$

Both give the result $\pi^2 - \frac{4\pi}3$

Comment: could you please elaborate on how you obtained the results

Comment: @Eugene - Do you mean the two setups?

Comment: yes for both. i am confused as to how you obtained them

Comment: i figured it out nvm. thanks btw!!